# Check element values with xs:unique

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to check that all **partNumber** elements in this XML file have unique values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plfBlocks xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../schema/plf_blocks.xsd">
    <plfPart>
        <partName>Screw</partName>
        <plfPart>
            <partName>Philipshead</partName>
            <plfPart>
                <partName>A</partName>
                <partNumber>01234</partNumber>
                <partNumber>01235</partNumber>
                <partNumber>01236</partNumber>
            </plfPart>
            <plfPart>
                <partName>B</partName>
                <partNumber>01244</partNumber>
                <partNumber>01256</partNumber>
                <partNumber>01234</partNumber>
            </plfPart>
        </plfPart>
    </plfPart>
    <plfPart>
        <partName>Nail</partName>
        <partNumber>010101</partNumber>
    </plfPart>
</plfBlocks>
```

This is my schema file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="plfBlocks">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="plfPart" type="plfPartType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:unique name="uniqueParts">
            <xs:selector xpath="partNumber"/>
            <xs:field xpath="text"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="plfPartType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="partName" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="partNumber" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="plfPart" type="plfPartType"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

The above xml-code validates even though one partNumber is duplicated. I have tried different versions for the xpath expression in xs:unique. "//partNumber" seems not to be supported by XML Schema. Will "partNumber" check all occurences?

This seems so basic, but how do I get it to work?

This is the solution I came up with after help from Michael and some further experimenting:

```
<xs:unique name="uniqueParts">
    <xs:selector xpath=".//partNumber"/>
    <xs:field xpath="."/>
</xs:unique>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<xs:selector xpath=".//partNumber"/>`

Comment: Thank you! I also changed to <xs:field xpath="."/>